# Mongo db join query or complex query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, routes, mongodb-query, objectid

Events are my collection name and I want to fetch all the events but I only want to display events which are not applied by a student where student is another collection.And i have Apply_event collection which contains student id and event id i want to render only those events in the form of a array.

```js
route.post('/student_apply_event/:_id', async (req, res) => {

    const applicant = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.session.student_id);
    const { event_id } = req.body;
    await Apply_event.create({ applicant: applicant, events_applied: event_id });
    res.redirect('/student_events');
})
```

I tried this code and my model is

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const apply_eventsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    applicant: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Student'
    },
    events_applied: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Event'
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Apply_event', apply_eventsSchema);
```

Comment: What's the question or problem that you are trying to get answered here?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.